# scp gives "[file] not a directory" error when using parameters

Tags: bash

I created a custom command in my `.bashrc` file which is:

```
function copySomething{
    scp "$1" somesshalias:~/
}
```

Whenevery I type `copySomething filename.txt` it gives me `filename.txt: Not a directory`. However: When I type `scp filename.txt somesshalias:~/` it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

- .bashrc is sourced
- removing the target file doesnt change anything

*Solved!*

I sourced the bashrc after every change but it seems like the old function did not get replaced by the new one. Restarting my console fixed the problem. Should have done that earlier...

Comment: you mean `-P 22`?

Comment: No - same outcome. I am not sure what `-P` should have changed, though

Comment: Could be a possible `scp` bug https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1768, check your versions if this is the case

Comment: solved! Its actually working but sourcing did not overwrite the old function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sourcing was the problem.

I sourced the bashrc after every change but it seems like the old function did not get replaced by the new one. Restarting my console fixed the problem. Should have done that earlier...